# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. na declaração de um objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Está ocorrendo um erro no meu código apenas quando eu publico, qunado estou debugando funciona normalmente.
o erro é o seguinte: "*Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.*"
meu código:

```
MkfFile file = new MkfFile();

public class MkfFile
{
    private List<FileData> _files { get; set; }
    private List<string> errors { get; set; }
    public MkfFile()
    {
        this._files = new List<FileData>();
        this.errors = new List<string>();
    }
    private class FileData
    {
    }
}
```

Se eu comento a linha "*MkfFile file = new MkfFile();*" ele funciona normalmente, alguém sabe me dizer onde está o erro?

Comment: O fonte está exatamente da forma com que você colocou na pergunta?

Comment: Em qual linha o erro ocorre?

Comment: Alguma novidade?

Answer (score 5):

Você não pode declarar uma variável fora da classe!
Ela tem que estar contextualizada em algum objeto. Por isso que quando você comenta a linha, dá tudo certo, porque não há variáveis declaradas soltas no arquivo fora da classe.

Pelo que entendi você quer declará-la como global:

```
public class MkfFile
{
    private List<FileData> _files { get; set; }
    private List<string> errors { get; set; }
    MkfFile file = new MkfFile();

    public MkfFile()
    {
        this._files = new List<FileData>();
        this.errors = new List<string>();
    }
    private class FileData
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas acho que o guri abandonou a pergunta. +1.

Comment: Pois é, ele deve ter percebido o erro e não postou aqui. :)

Comment: na verdade eu estava tentando usar uma variável que pensei estava definida no meu web.config de debug, e não no web.config q eu estava usando no publish... desculpe, tinha esquecido totalmente da pergunta

Comment: @LeonelSanchesdaSilva creio eu que nem deve ter voltado para o stackoverflow. assim como muitos, veio só para pegar a resposta para um problema